# How to make the last element in the nav display as a link

Tags: html, css

in my navbar the first three li elements are displayed as a links but the last one is not?
I really cant find where is the problem
this the html code :

```
<ul class="navMenu" id="navMenuId">
      
    <li class="main_links1"><a href="x" class="main_links1">Home</a></li>
    <li class="main_links2"><a href="x" class="main_links2">About</a></li>
    <li class="main_links3"><a href="x" class="main_links3">Contact us</a></li>
  
   <li class="main_links4"> <div class="dropdown">
    
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Universities</a></li>
   
      
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="x" class="drop1">Lebanese University</a>
        <a href="x" class="drop2">American University of Beirut</a>
        <a href="x" class="drop3">Lebanese American University</a>
        <a href="x" class="drop4">Université Saint-Joseph de Beyrouth</a>
        
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776;</a>
    
  </ul>`
```

the css is here because its a bit big: https://pastebin.com/0BxnshVw

any idea on how to fix it. I have tried several things but none worked

Comment: Seems like you have a bunch of styles defined for `.main_links1`, `.main_links2` etc. but none for `.main_links4`?

Comment: The `Universities` looks as a link, what do you mean by `the last one is not`? - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/zYKRWmb

Comment: i tried adding .main_links4 still didnt work

Comment: **Universities** seems like a link but it cant be pressed

Comment: The reason that 'nothing happens' is that for **Universities** you have href="#" which stays on the same page. The other have href="x" which result in a 404.

Comment: no even if put "x" the word Universities is still unclickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have div's and a's directly under an ul element. you should probably move the last closing `</li>` to the end of the block:

```
<ul class="navMenu" id="navMenuId">
   <li class="main_links1"><a href="x" class="main_links1">Home</a></li>
   <li class="main_links2"><a href="x" class="main_links2">About</a></li>
   <li class="main_links3"><a href="x" class="main_links3">Contact us</a></li>
   <li class="main_links4">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Universities</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="x" class="drop1">Lebanese University</a>
            <a href="x" class="drop2">American University of Beirut</a>
            <a href="x" class="drop3">Lebanese American University</a>
            <a href="x" class="drop4">Université Saint-Joseph de Beyrouth</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776;</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

your last link will then open if you hover it.

Comment: sorry but how can I hover it?

Comment: @mrreaper72 Hovering is when you move your mouse over the link

Comment: its hovered but not working
anyway thank you I managed to fix it

Comment: @mrreaper72 here is a jsfiddle which is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/x584zn3a/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody I managed to fix it

```
.navMenu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I removed the absolute positioning